# How To Event track a particular event with Google Analytics?

Tags: forms, google-analytics, event-tracking

I don't have a separate thank you/confirmation page to track Goal Conversions from a particular landing page. So, I need to Event track a "Submit Form" button of the landing page to count number of Form Submission as Goal Conversions from that page.

How to Event Track the "Submit Form" button so that it shows on Goal Completions pages when someone submits form.

Comment: Which language? What platform? Please be clear on what you need.

Comment: Web Server: Apache, Frameworks: PHP,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you will find how to create a goal that is based on a specific Event instead of a page view:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032415?hl=en#goal_types

To dispatch the Event expected by the Goal, i will recommend you to use this jQuery plugin (i'm the author) which was built for easily setup Event Tracking for Google Analytics:

https://github.com/DiegoZoracKy/google-analytics-event-tracking.

The result of your code will be something like this:

```
$.googleAnalyticsEventTracking({
    targetSelector: '#id-of-the-form', // it can be any jQuery selector
    events: {
        eventType: 'submit',
        gaEventData: {
            category: 'Form', // The same as you will set on the Goal setup
            action: 'Sent', // The same as you will set on the Goal setup
            label: 'Sign Up' // The same as you will set on the Goal setup
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the google analytics script in a file say analyticstracking.php, then include the file as follows:

```
<?php include_once("analyticstracking.php"); ?>
```

The code to be saved in analyticstracking.php can be found from google analytics site.

Here is a Google Developers link for sample [Google Analytics Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/other/mobileWebsites)

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your link:

onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'Button', 'Click', 'Purchase Details');"

You can edit the 3 options after event and then you must go into Google Analytics and set up the goal based upon the event (fairly easy to do)